# Resigning as Moderator from TWP

Tags: discussion, moderators

As most of you know, Monica was removed as a moderator over the weekend by the SE staff. It wasn’t her decision, and there **simply wasn't any justification for it**.

I scoured all the data I could over the last 24 hours, listened to the chatter in the private moderator room, and simply could not find any data that justified the actions taken.  This *stack* has taken a turn where I simply can no longer follow.

I have made the **difficult** decision of stepping down.  I wanted to stay on until after the election, but after seeing all the data, I can't do it in good faith.  Its simply not right what was done, what is being forced upon all of us, etc.

To echo Snow, Good luck to you and all who follow.

Comment: Best of luck, you're a good chap

Comment: Thank you for your support and for all you have done for The Workplace.

Comment: @Kilisi Thank you sir.  Keep the lights on in here please.  ;-}

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about this and the recent problems that have caused many other moderators to resign. I wish you well and I hope SE can sort out their issues.

Comment: Management at Stack Exchange is severely broken. All of the sites problems start at the top and trickle down. There will be no meaningful change until we get rid of management.

Comment: You've stepped down, SE has made promises, and Monica's situation is still unresolved. Why did you ask for reinstatement, if you felt this way? Nothing **still** hasn't be done.

Comment: @FrankerZ Because I changed my mind.  Stepping down did not move the ball in any direction either.  Also, as now its a legal matter, it could be months or even a year before any resolution is made.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

While I'm writing this on "your" thread Mister Positive I'm saying this equally to Snow and Jane as well;

I'm sorry to see you all go - not because I think you've made the wrong decision, on the contrary I think you've all made the right call. I'm just sorry it became necessary.

You've all been excellent moderators and if the last couple of years on Workplace SE have taught me anything it is that this is one of the sites that places quite high demands on it's mod team. And I feel the stack has benefited more than it knows from having an excellent at the helm.

While obviously Monica's "departure" wasn't her choice the same goes for her as well, I'm active on multiple stacks that she formerly moderated on and have interacted with her a few times over the years and I've always found her to be a truly excellent mod, both in taking up the hammer when needed and *building* the communities whenever she could.

So to Mister Postive, Jane, Snow, and of course Monica - **thank you.**

Answer (score 25):

When I recently had a problem on Workplace you, Mister Positive, were the only person (mod) I found to be genuinely positive and try to help resolve the issue

(as opposed to the community team, who compounded the problem by drawing attention to it, posted it on Twitter and then sent me a rude negatively-toned email when I called them out on their outright lies)

I think forcing you into leaving is a true loss to The Workplace, so thank you personally and good luck in your future!

---

Allow me this small pettiness as I sign off in a truly community-spirited manner, as I received:

```
We will not respond on the issue further.

Regards,
Stack Overflow Team
```

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for all the hard work as a diamond moderator - as a former diamond mod on RPG.SE I know how much thankless work is involved.

Thank you also for the principled stand, I would like to think that if my mod team had a fellow mod treated this way by the CMs we'd have mass resigned in protest as well. Well done.