# Calm down, nothing to see here

Tags: discussion

Seriously, everyone, calm down.

With or without moderators, we are all adults here, the place isn't going to collapse under it's own weight, get overrun by trolls, and get carried off into the swamp.

We haven't had a mountain of nasty comments, troll questions, or spam.

We don't need to go rushing in, or lose our minds if we don't.

Do you still have your family, friends, job, et cet?

Perspective people, perspective.

Comment: 2 mods reinstated, congrats to them both

Answer (score 11):

I am of the idea that Mods are *exception handlers*. TWP Community is strong and I trust that even without the guidance of mods the Community will organically handle itself and survive.

Speaking of Mods, seems that Snow and Mr. Positive have been reinstated as they requested (as per my understanding, with the goal of helping TWP and not letting the SE situation take a toll on the Community), so I am sure we will be Ok for now...:

[image]

Comment: That's the way it should be.  Over moderated forums just shut down