# Mister Positive: Thank you, and how can we help you?

Tags: discussion

As someone who finds this site and network useful, I'd like to say that I'm really grateful for your commitment to the site. I know it isn't easy, and I can't imagine how hard the recent events must have made it.

What do you need us community members to do to help you?

Is there a way that we can encourage earlier moderator elections to take some of the load off?

Comment: snark.  He loves snark.  also, argue with other users as often as possible.  </sarcasm>

Comment: A slightly older related post: [No more active ♦ moderators. How should we keep the site in order?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6333/no-more-active-moderators-how-should-we-keep-the-site-in-order)

Comment: Soneone's gotta say it...  Ready Player One?

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica I'm surprised that doesn't happen more really, (I think there was one months ago, but that's it). This is a handle I've used for years, and was born of my frustration at having to think up online names - so I stick with the "default".

Comment: @PlayerOne I tend to change online handles quite often.  I've had "The snark knight", "Prince of Snarkness", "Loki",  "Batcat_dom", "locrianlyric", "Lokean", "Twingrin", and many many more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First and foremost, thank you.

At some point we will be having an election of at least one, if not two moderators.  As it currently stands SE does not run elections during this time of year, so it will be just me until January 2020 at the earliest.

What can you do?

1. Keep the review queues clear
2. Close garbage questions
3. Flag offensive comments / answers

I appreciate the communities support!

Comment: Huh... I now don't see jmorg nor Jane on the mod page... only you and Lil... did I miss something besides the Monica situation? I recall that Jane and jmorg were still on that list even after the situation

Comment: @DarkCygnus Not sure about Jmorg, but Jane resigned her diamond.

Comment: @DarkCygnus MP is the last active mod.

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica and yet another potential Movie title: The Last Mod

Comment: @DarkCygnus I'm going to meme that quite aggressively. :D

Comment: @RichardSaysReinstateMonica we've got the whole saga by now lol

Comment: {In best Don LaFontaine voice...}  In a world where moderators quit left and right, there remains one, **true** dedicated mod, determined to rebuild....  Battling against  the darkness, he is the light...  Against all the negativity, he stands alone..  He is.....  **MR POSITIVE**

Comment: All I see is Neo still trying to bend the spoon as he moves trending wiki comments to chat; hope the spoon gives up before he does

Comment: In the wake of [Monica and SE coming to an agreement on the 23rd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio?cb=1) then there may be two additional moderators back before long if SE takes their final step of reinstating Monica.